# Divide DataFrame based on average values grouped by the value in a different column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame and I want to create two new DataFrames based on the average values in the ['Val'] column of the original Dataframe grouped the the column ['ID']. See below:

```
dict_ = {'ID': ['abc', 'def', 'def', 'abc'], 'Val' : [1, 57, 65, 9]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_)
df_avg = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)['Val'].mean()
low = df['ID'] == df_avg.loc[df_avg['Val'] <  55]['ID']
```

The code below does the first part

```
df_avg = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)['Val'].mean()
```

I then want two new DataFrames containing the first containing those rows from the first DataFrame with those ['ID']s which had average values below a threshold and other containging those ['ID']s whose average value was above the threshold.

```
low = df['ID'] == df_avg.loc[df_avg['Price'] <  55]['ID']
```

This is the logic of what I am trying to do but raises: ValueError can only compare identically-labelled Series objects.

I don't care about the labels I just want to match the values in the ['ID'] column.

Thanks

Comment: post a testable df fragment

Comment: I have now added a testable fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `df_avg['Val'] <  55` condition as mask for filtering/dividing on "below"/"above" dfs:

```
m = df_avg['Val'] < 55
low_ids = df[df['ID'].isin(df_avg[m]['ID'])]
up_ids = df[df['ID'].isin(df_avg[~m]['ID'])]
print(low_ids)
print(up_ids)
```

---

```
    ID  Val
0  abc    1
3  abc    9
    ID  Val
1  def   57
2  def   65
```